# wordpress image path, how to edit?

Tags: php, wordpress, path

i have a small problem in figuring out a path to a image var.
here is what happens. this is the image tag:

```
<img src="http://www.xxx.info/wp-content/uploads/http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51AV8B7CT2L._SL160_.jpg" class="attachment-135x135 wp-post-image" alt="Clean &amp; Sober" title="Clean &amp; Sober">
```

and this is how i would like it to be, without the `http://www.xxx.info/wp-content/uploads/`:

```
<img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51AV8B7CT2L._SL160_.jpg" class="attachment-135x135 wp-post-image" alt="Clean &amp; Sober" title="Clean &amp; Sober">
```

here is the wordpress code:

```
<?php $thumb = '';
$width = 135;
$height = 135;
$classtext = '';
$titletext = get_the_title();
$thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,$classtext,$titletext,$titletext,false,'Entry');
$thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"]; ?>
<?php print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, $classtext); ?>
```

more related functions:

```
 /* this function prints thumbnail from Post Thumbnail or Custom field or First post image */
function print_thumbnail($thumbnail = '', $use_timthumb = true, $alttext = '', $width = 100, $height = 100, $class = '', $echoout = true, $forstyle = false, $resize = true, $post='') {
    if ( $post == '' ) global $post;
    $output = '';
    $thumbnail_orig = $thumbnail;
    $thumbnail = et_multisite_thumbnail($thumbnail);

    $cropPosition = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'etcrop', true) ? get_post_meta($post->ID, 'etcrop', true) : '';
    if ($cropPosition <> '') $cropPosition = '&amp;a=' . $cropPosition;

    if ($forstyle === false) {
        if ($use_timthumb === false) {
            $output = $thumbnail_orig;
        } else { 
            $output = '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/timthumb.php?src='.$thumbnail.'&amp;h='. $height .'&amp;w='. $width .'&amp;zc=1&amp;q=90'.$cropPosition.'"';
            if ($class <> '') $output .= " class='$class' ";
            $output .= " alt='$alttext' width='$width' height='$height' />";
            if (!$resize) $output = $thumbnail;
        }
    } else {
        $output = $thumbnail;
        if ($use_timthumb === false) {
            $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $output, $matches);
            $output = $matches[1][0];
        } else {
            $output = get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/timthumb.php?src='.$output.'&amp;h='.$height.'&amp;w='.$width.'&amp;q=90&amp;zc=1'.$cropPosition;
        }
    }
    if ($echoout) echo $output;
    else return $output;
    }
```

this is what i get returned `$output = $thumbnail_orig;` in the image tag.

i know that there should be a var for `http://www.xxx.info/wp-content/uploads/`
and another one for `http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51AV8B7CT2L._SL160_.jpg`

i want to remove the the website path to `uploads`.

i cant seem to figure it out,
All help appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong or misunderstanding the question, but I thought setting the path in WP is as simple as editing it in the admin panel, under settings, no?

DC

Comment: Oh why?  Can you provide some more detail?  And if indeed not, why on earth are you editing the WP core?